# data.table in place modification in R

Tags: r, data.table, deep-copy

Consider a `data.table` `DT` as follows.

```
DT <- iris
setDT(DT)
ad <- address(DT)

DT[, a := NA_integer_]
identical(address(DT), ad)
```

I am trying to insert the some information sequentially in `DT$a` using a loop.

```
a1 <- sample(1:1000, 50)
a2 <- sample(1:1000, 50)
a3 <- sample(1:1000, 50)
```

As you can see this leads to copying of `DT` for the follwing method.

```
DT$a[1:50] <- a1
identical(address(DT), ad)
```

How to do this using `data.table` avoiding copying of `DT`?

Comment: `DT[1:50, a1 := sample(1:1000, 50)]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (i in 1:3) DT[1:(50*i), a := sample(1:1000, 50)]
```

or which makes more sense:

```
DT[ , a := sample(1:1000, 150)]
```